# Slow compilation of boost-based unit test suite

Tags: c++, unit-testing, gcc, boost, compilation

I use boost.test library to write unit tests for my application.

The problem is, when one particular *.cpp file containing test suite grows up to certain size, compilation of that file becomes extremely slow.

I use BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE macro to define test cases.

Boost version is 1.34.1

Build env is autotools + gcc 4.3 under Fedora 9.

I will highly appreciate if somebody will point out possible reasons of such behaviour.

Comment: Are you using source or the prebuilt library?

Comment: By what factor does it become slower, and how suddenly? Is it "add one more test case, and the whole thing is 10 times slower", or more like "at a certain point the additional time per test case starts rising"?

Comment: >>Are you using source or the prebuilt library?
I use prebuild library. Does it make any difference? 

>>By what factor does it become slower, and how suddenly? 
At some point it just starts to take about 3-5 minutes instead of 5 seconds, adding more test cases doesn't change the time significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You might run out physical memory and the system starts using the swap (file/partition) a lot more intensively than normaly (thrashing).

Comment: Well, it does use more memory then usual. But it is rather consequence not reason. The question is why does it use that much of memory?

Answer (score 1):

One way to try to find out what is going on is to use gcc option -Q and see where is the difference between normal and extremely slow case.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the same test suite to span multiple test files. This should alleviate your issues.